# Terraria libGL error i965_dri.so and swrast_dri.so

Tags: 16.04, drivers, games

I had installed Terraria 1.3.5 on Ubuntu 16.04, when I try to launch the game it gives me this error:

```
sudo ./start.sh
Running Terraria
libGL error: unable to load driver: i965_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: i965
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
X Error of failed request:  GLXBadContext
Major opcode of failed request:  154 (GLX)
Minor opcode of failed request:  4 (X_GLXDestroyContext)
Serial number of failed request:  120
Current serial number in output stream:  121
```

What should i do to fix this issue?

Comment: I did as adviced to no avail, I manually copied the drivers to the lib and lib64 game directories but didn't solve the problem.
I did this test, looking for errors:
`glxinfo | grep render`
I got this two important message:
`direct rendering: Yes`
`OpenGL renderer string: Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 5500 (Broadwell GT2)`
This means is working ok, right?

Comment: I tryed to install libgl1-mesa-dri, it's already installed:
libgl1-mesa-dri is already the newest version (17.3.3-0ubuntu1~16.04.1)